# remounting file system as rw in unix bash script

Tags: bash, unix, cron, mount

Hi all I need to remount a file system as read/write in a bash script

I've looked at several examples and my code looks right..in fact its working. However when I execute the bash file as root it still asks to enter a password. I can't do this as it is going to be run as a CRON job when I'm out of the office. I've tried several variations and  none work. Do you guys have any suggestions?

```
$MOUNT -o remount,rw $BACKUPDIR ;
if (( $? )); then
{
$ECHO "snapshot: could not remount $BACKUPDIR readwrite";
exit;
}
```

fi;

Comment: what are you mounting? you can specify the password as an option...

Comment: i can assure you it does..after I run the script I still get prompted for the password..I dont have a clue why its going on..Actually the destination is on a remote machine. maybe this has something to do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the password in the command line:

```
-o remount,rw,pass=password
```

Comment: If you must store the password in a script/program, please make sure you have good permissions set on it.  Also, if you store your code in a versioning system that your password might be permanently committed to history, that might be publicly available.